# How do I water berries in the Pokemon Global Link Dream World?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, pokemon-global-link

I can't water the berries; I can only plant them. I can click on the watering can and berries, but nothing happens. Do I water them right after I plant them? Is there a certain time I have to water them?

Comment: You may want to add in a bit more detail, such as what you have attempted.  As it stands, this doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Is that any better? There's not much to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't water a berry right after you plant it; it kind of "waters itself" at that moment. That's why the soil is dark: because it's already moist. As time passes, the soil's color becomes lighter, and that means it's drying. Then you can water the berry. If you plant a berry and check the next day, you'll probably notice it's dryer, and will be able to water it (unless the plant's fully grown).